# Clarifying operations identifying $\mathbb{R}[x]/\left<x^2 + 1\right>$ with $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

On page 281 of "A First Course in Abstract Algebra" by John B. Fraleigh, we have:

> Let $F = \mathbb{R}$, and let $f(x) = x^2 + 1$, which is well known to have no zeros in $\mathbb{R}$, and thus is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\left<x^2 + 1\right>$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, so $\mathbb{R}[x]/\left<x^2 + 1\right>$ is a field. Identifying $r\in\mathbb{R}$ with $r + \left<x^2 + 1\right>$, we can view $\mathbb{R}$ as a subfield of $E = \mathbb{R}[x]/\left<x^2 + 1\right>$.

I understand the bit about generating a field from the quotient of R over the maximal ideal. But my question is: why does identifying "$r\in\mathbb{R}$" as described above allow us to view $\mathbb{R}$ as a subfield of $E$?

The text goes on to say:

> Let $\alpha = x + \left<x^2 + 1\right>$. 
>   Computing in $\mathbb{R}[x]/\left<x^2 + 1\right>$, we find
>   $$
>   \alpha^2 + 1 = (x + \left<x^2 + 1\right>)^2 + (1 + \left<x^2 + 1\right>)
>   = (x^2 + 1) + (x^2 + 1) = 0.
> $$
>   Thus $\alpha$ is a zero of $x^2 + 1$.

I don't understand how we arrive at: $(x + \left<x^2 + 1\right>)^2 + (1 + \left<x^2 + 1\right>)$. It seems to me that $\alpha^2 + 1$ should simply be equal to the first term: $(x + \left<x^2 + 1\right>)^2 + 1$. I don't understand why we add the ideal again.

I also don't understand our choice of $\alpha$. There is something about factoring  polynomials that I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

It should be $\overline{1}$ in ${\bf{R}}[x]/\left<x^{2}+1\right>$, so $\overline{1}=1+\left<x^{2}+1\right>$.

Comment: are you saying I misquoted the text?

Comment: No, it is just that it is implicitly interpreted in that way.

Comment: Can you explain a little further please? Which question of mine are you responding to? What does the symbol $\overline{1}$ indicate?

Comment: $\overline{1}$ stands for the equivalent class of $1$ in ${\bf{R}}[x]/\left<x^{2}+1\right>$, which is simply $1+\left<x^{2}+1\right>$.

Comment: Just like $2+3$ in ${\bf{Z}}/5{\bf{Z}}$, it should mean as $\overline{2}+\overline{3}=(2+5{\bf{Z}})+(3+5{\bf{Z}})$.